# How can I set the line a string is found on as a variable, and then find the contents of that line number in another file?

Tags: variables, batch-file

Okay, this is kind of complicated so ill try to explain it as best as is can.
I am currently writing a simple program for my own use using notepad.
I am using the language batch and running the program through Command Prompt.

Part of the Program lets you access an account you created with username and password:

```
set /p USERNAME1= Username?
findstr /n "%USERNAME1%" Usernames.txt
```

In Usernames.txt are the usernames of each account that has been created, one per line.
If your username is found, it is displayed along with the line number before it in the program.

It then asks for your password:

```
set /p PASSWORD1= Password?
```

This is where the problem starts. When the accounts are created, the usernames are stored, one per line, in Usernames.txt , and so are the passwords but in Passwords.txt
I need the program to check if the password you typed is the same as the password on the same line number the username is on, in Passwords.txt
I know this is complicated but if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you able already to display the line number of the usersnames.txt, or still not?

Comment: yes but only with the username after it

Comment: Well, if you know the linenumber of the user, why don't you read the N-th line of passwords.txt and compare it with the input password?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `findstr /N` to get the line number of `usernames.txt`, which is a good start. You're getting the entire line, prefixed with the line number and a colon `:`.

So `for /F` can be used to extract the number only. The option string `"tokens=1 delims=:"` defines to divide the found line at the (first) `:`, so the line number is separated from the user name.

Finally, another `for /F` can be used to get the line of the `passwords.txt` files.

Putting all those things together, the following code snippet emerges:

```
set /P USERNAME1=Username? 
set /P PASSWORD1=Password? 
set /A LINENUMBER=0
for /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%I in (
  'findstr /N /I /X /C:"%USERNAME1%" "\path\to\usernames.txt"'
) do (
  set LINENUMBER=%%I
  goto :CONTINUE1
)
:CONTINUE1
set /A LINENUMBER-=1
if %LINENUMBER% lss 0 (
  exit /B
) else if %LINENUMBER% equ 0 (
  set SKIPPING=
) else (
  set SKIPPING=skip=%LINENUMBER%
)
for /F "usebackq %SKIPPING% delims=" %%I in (
  "\path\to\passwords.txt"
) do (
  if "%%I" equ "%PASSWORD1%" (
    goto :CONTINUE2
  )
  exit /B
)
:CONTINUE2
rem do something...
```

So the variable `USERNAME1` holds the entered user name to search and `PASSWORD1` the entered password.

If the user name cannot be found in `usernames.txt`, or the entered password does not match the found one, the script is terminated using `exit /B`.

Note that user names are compared in a case-insensitive manner (`/I` switch), but the password are compared case-sensitively.

Comment: Thanks but im new to this so i dont really understand a lot of that, could you please explain what "tokens" and "delims" mean? and the /a /f /b etc, sorry to be a pain aha thanks

Comment: Okay... in general you can type a command and ` /?` to display help text in command prompt, for instance `for /?`, which displays help for the `for` command (and all its options like `tokens` and `delims`)...

Comment: @HarveyLloyd, I just added the `delims=` option to the second `for /F` loop which I simply forgot...